# why UIImageToMat neglect the third argument when being called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, opencv, computer-vision

In openCV library, specifically, in ios.h, the UIImageToMat is declared as:

```
void UIImageToMat(const UIImage* image,
                         cv::Mat& m, bool alphaExist = false);
```

but When UIImageToMat is called, why people neglect the third argument?
for example:

```
UIImageToMat(image, cvImage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen in the function prototype, the third argument has a default value of `false`: `... bool alphaExist = false`. Hence, in use cases when there is no alpha, there is no need to explicitly specify the last argument.

Comment: why not just put the third argument into the main body of the method ? And instead, only require two argument for the method, which would be more clear.

Comment: Because then you could not support the cases where `alphaExists` needs to be `true`.

Comment: So you are saying the method can also be called like UIImageToMat(image, cvImage, true) so as to support the case when the alphaExists needs to be true?